# How to integrate a dynamic graph in a webpage?

Tags: html, excel, web, flot, plotly

I am getting dynamically generated data from my Raspberry PI in .csv format and I want to make a webpage for my institute to analyze the waveform of the output . The main feature of this graph is that the graph should auto-update according to the modified data. How should I go about making this?

Comment: ***o.0 what have you tried?***

Comment: use highchart plugin for graph there are almost all type of graph in it and generate from your dynamic data

Comment: there are several libraries you can use. i tend to use Chart.js. (http://www.chartjs.org/)

Comment: Question is too broad as it is. If you want to use Flot look at this [example](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/realtime/index.html) from there page.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the solution you are looking for must work in HTML 5 and JavaScript where there is NO server side processing. The raspberry pi posts a file to the server. 
We are using morris charts which is JavaScript library
http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/
Morris uses a json format
1: read the csv file 
2: convert the csv data to a json object 
3: initialise the chart

try this example csv data

"elapsed","value",b
"Oct-12",24,2
"Oct-13",34,22
"Oct-14",33,7
"Oct-15",22,6
"Oct-16",28,17
"Oct-17",60,15
"Oct-18",60,17
"Oct-19",70,7
"Oct-20",67,18
"Oct-21",86,18
"Oct-22",86,18

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {

   $.ajax({
     url: "linechartdata.csv",
     success: function(data) {
       processData(data)
     }
   });
 });


 function processData(data) {
   var record_num = 3; // or however many elements there are in each row
   var dataLines = data.split(/\r\n|\n/);
   var entries = dataLines[0].split(',');
   var records = [];

   var headers = entries.splice(0, record_num);
   console.log(dataLines.length)
   for (var i = 1; i < dataLines.length; i++) {
     var obj = dataLines[i].split(',');
     if (obj.length == headers.length) {
       var tarr = [];
       for (var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
         //doing it this way to get strings and numbers
         var field01;
         var field02;
         var field03;
         if (j == 0) {
           field01 = obj[j]
         }
         if (j == 1) {
           field02 = obj[j]
         }
         if (j == 2) {
           field03 = obj[j]
         }
         var o = {
           elapsed: field01,
           value: field02,
           b: field03
         }
         records.push(o);
       }       
     }
   }
   initChart(records)
 }

 function initChart(records) {

   var chart = Morris.Line({
     element: 'morris-chart-network',
     data: records,
     axes: false,
     xkey: 'elapsed',
     ykeys: ['value', 'b'],
     labels: ['Download Speed', 'Upload Speed'],
     yLabelFormat: function(y) {
       return y.toString() + ' Mb/s';
     },
     gridEnabled: false,
     gridLineColor: 'transparent',
     lineColors: ['#5b6b79', '#a5a5a5'],
     lineWidth: [2, 1],
     pointSize: [0, 2],
     fillOpacity: .7,
     gridTextColor: '#999',
     parseTime: false,
     resize: true,
     behaveLikeLine: true,
     hideHover: 'auto'
   });
 };
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Morris Chart</title>
</head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div>Morris Chart</div>
  <div id="morris-chart-network" style="width:800px;height:600px">
  </div>
  <div>
    example
  </div>
```